# Capturing the data entered in an HTML form by a user, and displaying it on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, django

As my course project, I am making a supermarket management system. I am using Django with MySQL.

I have already connected these two, and I am able to send data to the database and retrieve the same from it just fine.

I have a relation in MySQL for PRODUCTS (product_id, product_name, brand_name, price). After the cashier enters the name of the product and the quantity that the customer wishes to purchase, I want the information related to that product along with the quantity to be displayed on the same page. Since a customer can purchase many different products, I want the information to be displayed as and when the cashier enters the names of those products.

Then, I want to retrieve the information of all those products that were added by the cashier, and store it in the database in a relation called ORDERED_ITEMS (order_id, product_id, quantity) [order id is a foreign key].

I have no clue as to how to go about doing these things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**transaction.html:**

```
<form action="/transaction" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="order_id">ORDER ID</label>
    <input type="number" id="order_id" name="order_id" value="{{ next_order_id }}" disabled>

    <h3>ADD PRODUCTS :</h3>

    <label for="product_id"> Product ID</label>
    <select name="product_id" id="product_id">

        <option disabled selected="true"> --Select -- </option>
        {% for product in AllProducts %}
        <option value="{{ product.product_id }}"> {{ product.product_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}

    </select>

    <label for="quantity">QUANTITY</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">

    <!--On pressing this button, the data entered should be shown in a table on the same page-->
    <input type="button" class="send-message-cta" value="ADD PRODUCT">


    <input type="submit" class="send-message-cta" value="PROCESS TRANSACTION">
</form>

</html>
```

**models.py:**

```
class OrderedItems(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField()
    product_id = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_name)
```

**views.py:**

```
def transaction(request):


    AllProducts = models.Product.objects.order_by('product_name').all()
    next_order_id = models.Order.objects.count() + 1
    
    context = {'next_order_id': next_order_id, 'AllProducts': AllProducts}

    if request.method == "POST":
        order_id = next_order_id
        customer_ph_no = request.POST['customer_ph_no']
        product_id = request.POST['product_id']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']

        
        obj_ordereditems = models.OrderedItems(order_id=order_id, product_id=product_id, quantity=quantity)
        obj_ordereditems.save()

    return render(request, 'transaction.html', context)
```

I am a total novice when it comes to web development, pardon my silly mistakes.